# Cloudinary Widget for Image Upload in Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cloudinary

I have a form component for creating / updating a playlist. This includes some input fields, like "Name" and "Description". I also have an image upload button which opens the Cloudinary Widget. The problem is that once the widget is opened, it auto-submits my form.

I don't see any props for the cloudinary widget that would prevent this. Every example I see of people using this widget is JUST to upload an image, not in conjunction with a form.

(I'm using Semantic UI's React library for styling)

Is this not possible?

```
//form 
<Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <Form.Field required>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input
            placeholder='Name'
            value={this.state.name}
            name="name"
            onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)}
        />
    </Form.Field>
    <Form.TextArea
        label='Description'
        value={this.state.description}
        placeholder='Description'
        name="description"
        onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)}
    />
    <Form.Field >
        <label>Image</label>
        <Button onClick={() => this.openWidget()}>Upload Photo</Button>
        {/* <input id="upload" type="file" name="image" onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)}/> */}
    </Form.Field>
    <Button type='submit'>Submit</Button>
</Form>

//button callback to open widget

openWidget = () => {
        window.cloudinary.createUploadWidget(
         {
           cloudName: CLOUD_NAME,
           uploadPreset: "u9gezupm"
         },
         (error, result) => {

           if (result && result.event === "success") {
             // debugger
             this.setState({
               image: `https://res.cloudinary.com/${CLOUD_NAME}/image/upload/${result.info.path}`, uploaded: true
             });
           }
         }
       ).open()
      }
```

I would like the process to be as follows:

1. Form Button Clicked
2. Form Modal Opened
3. Name / Description fields filled out
4. Image button clicked
5. Cloudinary Widget opens
6. User uploads image.
7. Successful upload closes widget, back to form with image preview.
8. User clicks "Submit" to submit the form, sending the data to the backend / Cloudinary.

I am open to other alternatives to Cloudinary as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to reproduce this. Does this happen with plain JavaScript and are you able to share a CodePen/JSFiddle or similar snippet that reproduces this issue (JS/React)? In addition, I would also try to use `e.preventDefault();` within the openWidget(e) callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Button type="button" onClick={() => this.openWidget()}>Upload Photo</Button>
```

Comment: [edit]ing your answer and adding some context would make it far more useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. For anyone else that will stumble upon this issue, the problem lies with the eventhandler of cloudinary when you run the
`open();` function, or `this.openWidget();` in your case.

What you need to do is to call the `prevenDefault();` in your onClick callback function to prevent the widget from auto-submitting the form when it opens.

This is how it would look like in your case:

```
 <Form.Field >
  <label>Image</label>
  <Button 
    onClick={(e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.openWidget()
    }}>Upload Photo</Button>
</Form.Field>
```

Hope this solves your problem.